# Pusher doesn't trigger events in the client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, pusher

I'm trying to use Pusher/Node.js, I've configured then runned the app (following [this tutorial](http://github.com/pusher/pusher-realtime-chat-widget#nodejs)), but there is a problem in the API it doesn't trigger data to the client ([error line](http://github.com/pusher/pusher-realtime-chat-widget/blob/gh-pages/src/nodejs/app.js#L69) ).

My customizations:

- [chat.html](http://pastebin.com/qR1jCD0M)
- [app.js](http://pastebin.com/4wsV9HBk)
- [PusherChatWidget.js](http://pastebin.com/gDF054Xr)

What's wrong? Is the problem coming from Pusher API?

Comment: what happens instead?

Comment: @aredridel, nothing!